# Like button stuck at 1k on our homepage

Tags: button, facebook-like

I understand that the like button will display as even thousands once you pass 1,000 fans. But we have some 4800 fans yet our button still says "1k" likes on our homepage (www.10x10act.org). Why is it stuck?

Answer (score 0):

your like button shows the likes of http://10x10act.org/.
But you want to see the likes of http://www.facebook.com/10x10act.
Changing the href property the fb:like tag accordingly may help.